# Why is the file reading the last line of a row and the first one of the second row

Tags: java, file, csv, java.util.scanner

While reading a Excel CSV file using a scanner with a comma delimiter, its reading the last node in the first row but also reading the first node of the next row at the same time.

```
            int counter = 0;
            String[] u = new String[3];
            for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                String a = in.next();
                u[counter] = a;
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

After using Debugger, I noticed when it reached to the last element it combined them making something like -14256\r\n-14323

-14256 = Last element of first row
-14323 = First element of next row

Comment: By the way, you might consider delegating the mundane chore of reading/writing of data files to a library such as [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scanner took only the comma as the delimiter. But you want it to accept also the end of a line as another delimiter.

I assume that you instantiate the Scanner like this, using [`Scanner::useDelimiter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner( inputStream ).useDelimiter( "," );
```

*If* I get the Pattern definition right, it should be:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner( inputStream ).useDelimiter( ",|\\R" );
```

The \R stands for

> Linebreak matcher: Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to \u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]

Refer to the documentation for [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the details.

Answer (score 1):

A CSV file contains lines of text where each line contains values separated by commas. Hence I suggest that you read the file line by line and then [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) each line on the commas. Something like...

```
java.io.FileReader fr = new java.io.FileReader("path to file");
java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(fr);
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    // Add code here to handle the "fields".
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Note that the above code is not a complete solution but a starting point. For instance, I haven't closed the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Or just `Files.lines()`.